Orbit type stratification
Let $G$ be a complex reductive group acting on an affine smooth variety $X$ with finite stabilisers, i.e., $|\mathrm{Stab}_G(p)|<+\infty$ for any $p\in X$. Then we can define
$$X_{(E)}=\{ p \in X\,|\, \mathrm{Stab}_G(p)\ \text{is conjugate to } E\}.$$
I believe that $X_{(E)}$ is smooth for any $E$ from MO1 and MO2, and I am finding a reference about this.
So, if there are no errors, can you give me a reference (paper or textbook) about the smoothness of $X_{(E)}$?
Or if I made some errors, I appreciate any of your comments.

I don't know a reference, but from MO1 the proof is immediate: $X_{(E)}$ is the disjoint union of the smooth subvarieties $X_{H}:={p\in X,|,\operatorname{Stab}_G(p)=H } $ for $H$ conjugate to $E$.
